# How to query wikidata for the number of taxonomic entities that have a wikipedia page?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to find out how many biological taxonomic entities have an article on wikipedia, across all languages.

I am able to get the number of entities in wikidata, but many of these don't have an article on wikipedia.

Below is the SPARQL query I used. How do I modify it so it only counts taxons with a wiki article?

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q16521 .
}
```

Comment: `SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q16521 .
  hint:Prior hint:runFirst true.
  ?article schema:about ?item . 
  ?article schema:isPartOf [ wikibase:wikiGroup "wikipedia" ] .
}` - it's untested, you might need some other query hints to avoid a timeout I guess

Comment: if you get a timeout, just try the Qlever endpoint which is very fast: https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/GfY0hQ